# Aspose cells for .NET find out on which page is cell placed

Tags: .net, excel, cells, aspose

Does exist method how to find out on which page in Excel worksheet is located cell using .NET and Aspose Cells? I know on which row cell is.

I have found method

> worksheetData.HorizontalPageBreaks.Count

However this method works only with manually added page breaks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cell.Worksheet](http://docs.aspose.com:8082/docs/display/cellsnet/Worksheet+Property) property to get it's parent worksheet.